# LinkedHashSet inside a LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a JSON response of the following format which I will be parsing to get the keys (key_as_String) and values (Expected_Usage and Actual_Usage) for each key.

```
"aggregations": {
    "Inner_aggregation": {
        "doc_count": 366,
        "Hours_aggregation": {
            "doc_count": 366,
            "by_day": {
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key_as_string": "2016-01-11",
                        "key": 1452556800000,
                        "doc_count": 1,
                        "Expected_Usage": {
                            "value": 5
                        },
                        "Actual_Usage": {
                            "value": 3
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key_as_string": "2016-01-12",
                        "key": 1452556800000,
                        "doc_count": 1,
                        "Expected_Usage": {
                            "value": 43
                        },
                        "Actual_Usage": {
                            "value": 2
                        }
                    },
                    .........,
                    .........
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I want to keep the insertion order as the KEYS returned by Elastic Search is already sorted. I also want to maintain the order of VALUES for each key.

Thinking of using LinkedHashmap and a LinkedHashSet for this.

```
LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashSet<Integer>> LinkedMap = 
              new LinkedHashMap<String,LinkedHashSet<Integer>>();

LinkedHashSet<Integer> LinkedSet = 
                      new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(); 
LinkedSet.add(3);
LinkedSet.add(4);
LinkedSet.add(2);

LinkedMap.put("2016/03/11",LinkedSet);


for(Map.Entry m:LinkedMap.entrySet()){
   System.out.println("Key is : " + m.getKey() + " Values: " + m.getValue());
  }
```

Are there any better alternatives in terms of memory and performance?

Comment: Better in what sense? Performance, memory, code maintainability?

Comment: :) You picked two antagonistic dimensions in performance. Usually you can get extra speed if you sacrifice memory and vice-versa. :)

Comment: I see. These are my requirements in the order of importance.

1. Preserve key order and order of values inside the key
2. Performance
3. Memory

Would you suggest any other data structures?

Comment: In the context of your example: you already sacrifice the completeness of you integer, by storing them in a `Set` - thus losing duplicated values. As such, gotta ask yourself: is order still important? Also, you store what looks like a Date inside the key: a date object is likely more compact than the string representation (but you are gong to spend extra CPU with parsing and formatting them if they need to be read by human eyes).

Comment: "Would you suggest any other data structures? " On a general case: no. On a particular case, with the data structures specific to your needs, I might - that depends on those data structures and on the specifics of acquiring and consuming them.

Comment: Losing duplicate values - That was a good catch. Thank you! 

I think I should give you little more context. The maximum possible key values in the response is 365 and there'll be only 2 values for each Key. (Duplicate values are allowed in a key). That is why am not that worried about memory. I don't want to spend so much CPU at the same time as that'll basically ruin Elastic search's magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many choices, **mainly determined by how you are going to consume the acquired data** - e.g. if you don't care about the calling code modifying your data, designing structures with public members will result in the least CPU pressure.

> The maximum possible key values in the response is 365 and there'll be only 2 values for each Key.

I see. The I recommend dropping the `LinkedHashSet` and writing a custom class to hold those two integers **unboxed** (dont waste CPU in converting `int` to `Integer` and back):

```
public class ExpectedVsActual {
  // if you don't care too much of your data integrity
  // along other lines of coding, make those public
  // and forget about getters
  protected int expected;
  protected int actual;

  public ExpectedVsActual(int exp, int act) {
    this.expected=exp;
    this.actual=act;
  }
  public int getExpected() {
    return this.expected;
  }
  public int getActual() {
     return this.actual;
  }
}
```

Then

```
LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<ExpectedVsActual>> myMap=...; // etc
```

Of course, if you don;t need to search through the keys, then you dont need a map.

If you want individual entries for each key, maybe it's better to wrap each entry as a structure:

```
public class MyEntryRepresentation {
   protected String dateStr;

   // ArrayList: faster iteration by position
   // LinkedList: memory conservative - doesn't allocate more than necessary
   protected List<ExpectedVsActual> data;

   public MyEntryRepresentation(String date) 
     this.dateStr=date;
     this.data=new ArrayList<ExpectedVsActual>();
   }

   public void addEntry(int expected, int actual) {
     this.data.add(new ExpectedVsActual(expected, actual));
   }

   public List<ExpectedVsActual> getValues() {
     // if you don't care what the caller will do with your List 
     return this.data;
     // If you want to forbid them to modify the returned list
     // return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.data);
   }

   public String getDateStr() {
     return this.date;
   }
}
```

and then

```
LinkedHashMap<String, MyEntryRepresentation> map=... etc;

map.add(entry.getDateStr(), entry);
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Thanks Adrian!

Comment: You're welcome. (this is what SO is about after all)

Answer (score 1):

The linkedhashmap is use an Entry Array inside, And whatever you put a new value into the map, a new Entry is created and the new Entry have the point to refer previous entry. In Addition,  I would not suggest to use set because if you have same value between Expected_Usage and Actual_Usage, you will have one value inside the sets. I create a simple data structure to solve your issues, hope this can help.

```
public static class DataStructure{
    private final String key;
    private List<Integer> values;

    public DataStructure(String key){
        this.key = key;
        values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
    public void addValue(Integer value){
        values.add(value);
    }

    public List<Integer> getValues(){
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(values);
    }
    public String getKey(){
        return this.key;
    }
}
    List<DataStructure> datas = new ArrayList<DataStructure>();
    DataStructure data = new DataStructure("2016/03/11");
    data.addValue(1);
    data.addValue(2);

    datas.add(data);
```

Comment: Eric, Thank you very much! ArrayList is a good option and can do what i want. Your code will work for sure. But i think it won't guard against duplicate keys. I think LinkedHashMap + ArrayList will solve the issue.